# Replace NA in Column A, comparing column A and a list

Tags: r

I have a data.frame DF which contains two columns. Names and Score.
I than have a list (the.list) containing names. Some are equal to the names in names in DF$names.
I need to insert a number (2000) into DF$score, if the name is in the.list and the score is NA

The data:

```
DF.scores <- data.frame(c("steve", "anna", "albert", "john", "sarah", "lily"), c(2000, 1500, NA, NA, NA, 1750))
names(DF.scores) <- c("names", "score")
the.list <- c("anna", "steve", "john")
```

I need the data frame to end up like this:

```
names   score
steve   2000
anna    1500
albert  NA
john    2000
sarah   NA
lily    1750
```

I have tried subsetting the data, use which command but getting no results.

Comment: ...which is `DF.scores$score[DF.scores$names %in% the.list] <- 2000` in the replacement form

Comment: I don't think the above suggestions address the OP's criteria for setting the score to 2000, namely `if the name is in the.list and the score is NA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's simple, but where you have scores already in your dataframe that you might not want to change, it's hard to beat a simple ifelse statement:

```
DF.scores$score <- with(DF.scores,ifelse(names %in% the.list & is.na(score),yes=2000,no=score))
```

Comment: I don't think this answer address the OP's criteria for setting the score to 2000, namely `if the name is in the.list and the score is NA`.

Comment: @Snubian Thank you... I missed the second condition.  The edit will be posted shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `dplyr::mutate()` for this:

```
dplyr::mutate(DF.scores, score = ifelse(names %in% the.list & is.na(score), 2000, score))
```

This sets score to 2000 if both conditions are met, `names` is in `the.list` *and* `score` is `NA`.

```
> dplyr::mutate(DF.scores, score = ifelse(names %in% the.list & is.na(score), 2000, score))
   names score
1  steve  2000
2   anna  1500
3 albert    NA
4   john  2000
5  sarah    NA
6   lily  1750
```